# Axios and mongoose to build an API

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb

Can I use axios and mongoose to build an API? That's because I am new in the back-end developement, so I tried and I gotta an error like below, I was trying to do an API with axios and mongoose, but I don't know if i can use them together, I was kind to test this code to see if they work, but apparently not. So any suggestion to code better or is that correct what I am doing, is there other way ? I sure there is, but which recommendion you guys can make.

I want to create two separate files, one for controllers like "product.controller" and use my api to do all the requests that my differents controllers could need

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

product.controller.js

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model');
const api = require('../api/api');
mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);

// To create a new Product
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    const product = await api.create('/product', req.body);
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'The product has been created successfully !', product });
  };
```

api.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const baseURL = require('../config/database');


const list = async(key) =>{
    const content = await axios.get(baseURL.local.urlDataBase + key +'.json')
    if(content.data){
        const objects = Object
                                .keys(content.data)
                                .map(key=>{
                                    return{
                                        id: key,
                                        ...content.data[key]
                                    }
                                })
            return objects
    }
    return []
}

const get = async(key, id) => {
    const content = await axios.get(`${baseURL.local.urlDataBase}/${key}/${id}.json`)
    return {
        id: id,
        ...content.data
    }
}

 const create = async(key, data) =>{
    await axios.post(`${baseURL.local.urlDataBase}/${key}.json`, data)
    return true
} 

module.exports = {
    list, create
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about your code and what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sure! I'll paste my controller and api file

Comment: When are you getting that error? Is it the `axios.post` call? If the socket is hanging up, maybe the URL is bad or you are missing some required headers (like authorization).

Comment: yes, it is in the axios.post @Jacob, maybe it is headers, because I didn't add nothing like authorization, I run my application locally.

Comment: @Jacob, thanks dude it's working!